# Set the class on selected radio button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have exactly the same situation like [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) except select options I have radio buttons.

Html

```
<body ng-app="switchExample">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="selection" name="field1" value="field1"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="selection" name="field2" value="field2"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="selection" name="field3" value="field3"></input>
    </div>
    <code>selection={{selection}}</code>
<hr/>
<div class="animate-switch-container"
ng-switch on="selection">
  <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="settings">Settings Div</div>
  <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="home">Home Span</div>
  <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-default>default</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Angular:

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('switchExample', ['ngAnimate'])
 .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.selection = 'field1';
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Goal:

I'm struggling to set the class on div element wrapped around radio button, because radio button has `opacity:0` and I must work with `div` element.

Setting `ng-class="{checked: selection == 'selection'}"` gives class on all select options, which is what I don't want.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Let's say I select "home" in the select box. What should happen? What happens instead? Your title talks about radio buttons. But there is no radio button at all in the posted code. I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I updated the question with a goal in.

Comment: I don't see any ng-class code in your html, are you using it? Also, in your goal, the ngClass syntax is wrong. It should be ng-class="{'checked': selection == 'selection'}".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ng-class:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .class-if-selected {
        font-size: 21pt;
      }
      .class-ifnot-selected {
        color: blue;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ctrl.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <form>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="selection" name="field1" value="field1" />
        <span ng-class="(selection == 'field1' ? 'class-if-selected' : 'class-ifnot-selected')">One</span>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="selection" name="field2" value="field2" />
        <span ng-class="(selection == 'field2' ? 'class-if-selected' : 'class-ifnot-selected')">Two</span>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="selection" name="field3" value="field3" />
        <span ng-class="(selection == 'field3' ? 'class-if-selected' : 'class-ifnot-selected')">Three</span>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Two Strong Suggestions I Included in This Code

#### 1: Input tags are self-closing

`<input />` makes valid HTML and `<input></input>` would cause you problems down the road

#### 2: Use checkboxes or lose the divs

If you intend to allow multiple radio buttons to be selected at one time, use checkboxes. Users are more familiar with selecting multiple checkboxes whereas they usually expect one and only one selection with radio buttons. If you lose the divs and substitute one form tag around all of them, you can achieve the same result, the page will look the same but one and only one radio button will be able to be selected at a time.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Diederiks. Thanks for suggestions. I intend to allow only one option to be selected. And intention behind all that is that I want radio buttons to be visually hidden, and still selectable. So that is why I needed to have element wrapping radio button styled, when selected.